# Cannot change first letter to be uppercase and the rest lowercase using regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to make the first letter of a sentence uppercase and the rest lowercase using regex in Java.

I know functions like toLowerCase and toUpperCase exist but I MUST use regex for academic reasons.

If a word except the first word starts with a capital letter or written in mixed case,
the word should be converted to all lowercase letters. The first word should
start with a capital letter

john WaLKs into A New world. ----> John walks into a new world.

I've tried using something like this but it doesn't work and I don't know what to do.

data.replaceAll("([A-Z])","$1\L");

Comment: Do you mean `data = data.replaceAll("([A-Z])","$1\L");`? Strings are immutable, so `replaceAll` doesn't actually update the string directly.

Comment: I have to use regex otherwise I get a 0. I know functions like toLowercase exist. Also I use data = data.replaceAll and the regex is wrong.

Comment: Please quote your exercise (especially part about using regex) because what you want to do doesn't seem to make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should make it by passes, I mean first convert all to lowercase then Capitalize it